# RESTful: How to dynamically extend path via interface

Tags: java, web-services, rest, jax-rs

I have the following interfaces

```
@Path("/v1")
public interface IV1Api {

}

@Path("/Accounts/{AccountId}")
public interface IAccountsInstanceApi extends IV1Api {

}

@Path("/Users")
public interface IUsersListApi extends IAccountsInstanceApi {
    @GET
    Json listUsers();

    @POST
    Json createUser();
}

public UsersListResource implements IUsersListApi {
    // ...
}
```

I was expecting my user list resource path to be `/v1/Accounts/123/Users`, but it is `/Users`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think by putting @Path("/v1/Accounts/123/Users") above IUsersListApi interface will work.

Comment: Well true. But I'm looking for a way to extend paths from a previous implementation, not have an absolute path

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, but it doesn't work like this. You can do the following:

```
@Path(IAccountsInstanceApi.PATH)
public interface IAccountsInstanceApi extends IV1Api {
   String PATH = "/Accounts/{AccountId}";
}

@Path(IUsersListApi.PATH)
public interface IUsersListApi extends IAccountsInstanceApi {
   String PATH = IAccountsInstanceApi.PATH + "/Users";

    @GET
    Json listUsers();

    @POST
    Json createUser();
}
```

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks!